# Complicated grep commands not executing in shell script

Tags: bash, unix, grep, sh

I am trying to execute a couple of complicated grep commands via a shells script that work fin in the terminal manually executed.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.
The goal of the first grep is to get out any process id attached to the parent myPattern.  The 2nd get the process id of the process myPattern

Currently my shell script 
returns nothing for the 1st.
ignores the "grep -v 'grep'"  part in the 2nd.

```
#!/bin/sh

ps -ef | grep "$(ps -ef | grep 'myPattern' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" | grep -v grep | grep -v myPattern | awk '{print $2}'
ps -ef | grep 'myPattern' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'
```

This works fine when run in the terminal manually.  Any ideas where i have stuffed this up?

Comment: works just fine for me.

Comment: FYI use ` for better portability instead of $(

Comment: if you mean `bash`, then it's best to use `#!/bin/bash` at the top. Your system may have a bourne shell (or react as one) when you use the sh-bang `#!/bin/sh`. What do you see when you use `set -vx`? Good luck.

Comment: A nice technique to avoid the need for `grep -v grep` is to do `grep [m]yPattern`

Answer (score 0):

Your first command is vague. I don't think it would reliably do what you describe. It also does not guard against getting the id of the first grep call. The second one works for me. For the fists query it highly depends on the system you are using. It's easier to use pstree to show you the whole process tree under a pid. Like:

```
pstree -p 1782 | sed 's/-/\n/g' | sed -n -e 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\)).*/\1/p'
```

You need to limit pid to be a single value. If you have more values, then you have to loop through them. If you don't have pstree, then you can craft some loop around ps. Make note that even if you current commands worked, then thwy would catch only one level parent/child relationships. pstree does any level.

I also have to tell you that a process can escape original parent as a parent process by forking.

In any case without exact details what you are trying to achieve and *why*, and on what platform it is hard to give you a great answer. Also these utilities albeit present virtually everywhere are not as portable as one would wish.

One more note - /bin/sh is often not your current shell. On many linux systems user has a default shell of bash and /bin/sh is dash or some other shell variant. So if you see diffs with what you have in console and script, it can be difference in actual shell you are using.

Based on user feedback it would be much easier to have something like this in the java process launching script:

```
java <your params here> &
echo $! > /var/run/myprog.pid
```

Then the kill script would look like `echo /var/run/myprog.pid | xargs kill`. There are shorter commands but I think this is more portable. Give actual code if you want more specific.

Comment: This is all being done on a solaris environment.  The goal I am trying to achieve is part of a 2 step process.  The first script is used to kick of a shell script which executes a java program and runs it in the background.  The 2nd script needs to be able to terminate that java process.